# String to Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a launch Intent from a list of installed apps

```
Intent intent = packageManager
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);
```

If I start that intent with `startActivity(intent)` there'll be no problem.
But if I parse that intent to String and create a new intent from that String and then start Activity like this:

```
String s = intent.toString();           
Intent secondIntent = new Intent(s);
startActivity(secondIntent);
```

My app will crash. So is there any way I can parse the String back to Intent like the original intent?
(If anyone wonders why I'd want to do something stupid and unnecessary like this, I'm just omitting the details to keep the question short. Actually I want to store the launch intent in a database for later use so I have to store it in String)
EDIT: As @pskink suggest, using Intent#toUri and Intent#parseUri works perfectly

```
String s = intent.toUri(0);         
Intent secondIntent = Intent.parseUri(s, 0);        
startActivity(secondIntent);
```

Comment: try posting the crash logs...

Comment: see Intent#toUri()/Intent#parseUri()

Comment: Intent can not be casted to String. So better is to store package name into DB, and use `packageManager
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)` to get laucher intent when need.

Comment: is my answer worked out?

Comment: I'm sorry but my test device is currently has some problems. I'll post the logs later.

Answer (score 1):

As in Doc:

[Intent.toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#toString%28%29):

> Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of
>   this object.

means `Intent.toString()` is not return an ACTION which is required for Intent constructor as parameter.

If you want to prepare Intent using ACTION then try it as:

```
Intent secondIntent = new Intent(intent.getAction());
startActivity(secondIntent);
```

Comment: So is there any way I can change the intent to a String for storing and get that intent back from the stored String ?

Comment: @abc105:  why you want to store intent?

Comment: @abc105 use Intent#toUri()/Intent#parseUri()

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: for a later use

Comment: damn. My test device currently has some problems. I'll report the result later. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @abc105 So why not you store package names of applications into DB, and use them to retrieve lucher intent when need.

Comment: @abc105 dont store any package names, just use Intent#toUri()/Intent#parseUri()

Answer (score 0):

`intent.toString();` doesn't convert you `intent` to `string`, it returns a brief describtion of your intent:

> Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of
>   this object. Subclasses are encouraged to override this method and
>   provide an implementation that takes into account the object's type
>   and data.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
Intent intent = packageManager
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);


String s = intent.getAction();           
Intent secondIntent = new Intent(s);
startActivity(secondIntent);
```

Comment: No this does not help him :)

Comment: it is just modified check once

Comment: My test device currently has some problems. I'll report the result later. Thanks anyway

Comment: Actually I tried that and it did a weird thing, the "Complete action using" dialog popped up and it seemed to me all installed apps were in that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the intent?

```
 Intent secondIntent = new Intent(intent);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Intent)

Then looking at the source, this is how a copy works:

```
public Intent(Intent o) {
        this.mAction = o.mAction;
        this.mData = o.mData;
        this.mType = o.mType;
        this.mPackage = o.mPackage;
        this.mComponent = o.mComponent;
        this.mFlags = o.mFlags;
        this.mContentUserHint = o.mContentUserHint;
        if (o.mCategories != null) {
            this.mCategories = new ArraySet<String>(o.mCategories);
        }
        if (o.mExtras != null) {
            this.mExtras = new Bundle(o.mExtras);
        }
        if (o.mSourceBounds != null) {
            this.mSourceBounds = new Rect(o.mSourceBounds);
        }
        if (o.mSelector != null) {
            this.mSelector = new Intent(o.mSelector);
        }
        if (o.mClipData != null) {
            this.mClipData = new ClipData(o.mClipData);
        }
    }
```

Most of these fields have some type of getter when you check the `Intent` API. So you can duplicate this behaviour with methods like `intent.getAction()` `intent.getData()` etc

Comment: The main point is that I want to store the launch intent in a database which as far as I know, doesn't accept intent as a data type.

Comment: @Blundell Intent API has Intent#toUri()/Intent#parseUri()

Comment: @Blundell so it seems you didn't use it in action, do that..., see sources of Intent.toUriInner method, http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#toUriInner

Comment: I haven't tried this but I presume this will do the trick but taking a lot of work and making the database more complicated. I want to keep it simple and @pskink solution works well. Thanks anyway.